# Building the Facebook 3.x+ SDK on iOS

Tags: ios, build, facebook-sdk-3.0

I just downloaded the Facebook 3.27 SDK from the Facebook's developer account.

In the getting started section (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started), it mentions "Then build the SDK from source before you compile and run any samples".

It does not mention how to build the source.  Is this done through Xcode, or through a shell script?  If done through either, there is an error message where the build chokes on building "Bolts" with a "Directory not found".

Any ideas on how I'm supposed to build the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

It does actually mention how to build it:

> Then build the SDK from source before you compile and run any samples:
>
> ```
>   ./scripts/build_framework.sh
> ```

But I would just download it from the [link provided](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-ios-sdk-current.pkg) and skip the build step... It's not an 'AND'. It's there if you'd rather download it from github / install it via cocoapods. That step is not needed if you just download the .PKG file

Comment: OK.  It doesn't download from git in the terminal. Access denied.  Is simply entering that file into the command line enough to start the build?  Because entering that file path into the terminal reports a Bolts error.  We can't use cocoapods yet.

Comment: Have you tried just using the .PKG file and installing it via that one. Then you won't have to bother with building it

Comment: Yeah, I do and have run it the installer and grabbed the framework now.  I still would like to know how to properly build the framework, because we run into Facebook framework issues every time we do a synch or merge in SVN.